# How do I programmatically setup a userpool in AWS Cognito using Go APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have successfully setup a userpool using the standard AWS Cognito wizard. However I do need to use the AWS SDKs and APIs for adding additional functionality to my userpool. I am fairly new to AWS and I cannot find the right documentation to create a userpool using Go APIs.

For Reference: I need to create a userpool where every user's email is set as his username. I have read in the documentation that I need to call the CreateUserPool API and set the Username Attributes accordingly, but I do not know how to call the API or where do I start setting up these APIs?

I would really appreciate any guidance regarding the setup of userpools programmatically!

I am currently following this youtube tutorial, but not sure if its the right one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfKQEN65Vtg

Comment: you can refer this:  https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cognitoidentityprovider#Client.CreateUserPool